# Cannot set name of primary key constraint with table-per-type inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my EF Core 6.0 model, I use table-per-type inheritance. However, for migration purposes I need to customize the name of the primary key constraints in the involved entities (`BaseItem` and `DerivedItem`).

Below the configuration classes to set the primary key constraints using fluent API.

Entities:

```
public abstract class BaseItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[Table("DerivedItems")]
public class DerivedItem : BaseItem
{

}
```

Configurations:

```
public class BaseItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BaseItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BaseItem> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(item => item.ID)
            .HasName("PK_dbo.BaseItems");
    }
}

public class DerivedItemConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<DerivedItem>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<DerivedItem> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(item => item.ID)
            .HasName("PK_dbo.DerivedItems");
    }
}
```

When scaffolding the initial migration I get the following error:

> A key cannot be configured on 'DerviedItem' because it is a derived type.
> The key must be configured on the root type 'BaseItem'. If you did not
> intend for 'BaseItem' to be included in the model, ensure that it is not
> referenced by a DbSet property on your context, referenced in a
> configuration call to ModelBuilder, or referenced from a navigation on
> a type that is included in the model.

Is there a way to customize the name of the primary key constraints when table-per-type inheritance is used?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is there? I copied your exact code and can run well both `migrations add` and `db.Database.MigrateAsync()`, the result is correct, a table with the name `DerivedItems` and `ID` column.

Comment: Do you really need the .HasKey() in the derived class? Isn't that part only needed on the base class?

Comment: @Niklas: I need to customize the name of the primary key constraint in the derived class, which must be different than the constraint name in the base class. I don't know a way to do that without calling .HasKey() in the derived class. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @LukeVo: are you sure the configuration classes are called?

Comment: I found an interesting note in the EF Core documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance#table-per-type-configuration). It says: "If the primary key constraint is renamed the new name will be applied to all the tables mapped to the hierarchy, future EF versions will allow renaming the constraint only for a particular table when issue 19970 is fixed." Therefore, there is probably no solution to my problem for the time being.